# How can I determine an empty string when its contents is \0\0\0\0

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0

I have a SizeOfData variable of `byte[4]` which returns:

```
byte[0] == 0
byte[1] == 0
byte[2] == 0
byte[3] == 0
```

When I do `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(SizeOfData)` the string variable's length is 4 and `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` returns false however when I look at the string in Visual Studio there is nothing in it.

How can I determine that if it contains all \0\0\0\0 then do X else Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of linq magic

```
if (bytes.All(b => b == 0))
```

or the slightly better

```
if (bytes.Any(b => b != 0))
```

Comment: Better in what sense? Either of those will exit as soon as the condition is violated (first option) or satisfied (second option).

Answer (score 2):

> when I look at the string in Visual Studio there is nothing in it

What you mean, I'm assuming, is that when you hover the mouse over the string in the debugger (or add a watch, or inspect the locals, or otherwise view a visual representation of the string) it appears to be empty. This is because `\0`, like some other characters, is a non-printable character. These characters are there, but they do not cause a visual effect.

If you want to determine if the *byte array* is only zero, that's simple:

(Note that your array name above is invalid, so I'm going to call it `data`)

```
if(data.Add(b => b == 0))
{
    // is only null characters
}
```

However, it seems like you'd want something a bit more robust, and something that could work on strings. You can use a simple RegEx to replace the range of non-printable Unicode characters (your original string as in ASCII, I know, but once you parse it it's stored internally as UTF-16):

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "[\x00-\x1F]", "");
```

At this point, `string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)` should return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Before converting to string you could:

```
bool isNulls = SizeOfData.All(x => x == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle it earlier, you could check the byte array:

```
if(SizeOfData.Any(b => b != 0))
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```